# How to show ShareActionProvider in layout instead of menu item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sharing

In my application I want to show all the share action provider inside my layout instead of in menu item.I can easily show those using ShareActionProvider but as per project requirement I need to show in Listview  inside my layout.
I want to display all the possible share option inside my layout.

I want this kind of screen to be displayed[image: Wireframe]

Answer (score -1):

Following example shows you how to send text to another application.Put this code on event when you want the app chooser to share.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: I knew this, I want to display all the possible share option on my layout

Comment: You can try with `intent.setType("file/*")`.

Comment: Or try with `intent.setType("*/*");`

Comment: You completely misunderstood the problem, I want to paint the share option like facebook, whatsapp or email inside my UI